# Create a custom capability to allow an 'Editor' to edit only 'Subscriber' users

Tags: plugin-development, capabilities

I want to create a new "Moderator" role (in between Administrator and Editor), that can edit only "Subscriber" type user accounts.

I can create the role and add existing wp capabilities, but I don't know how to create a new capability, 'edit_subscriber', that can do that.

Any insight appreciated.